# What is "opening her Caesar" referring to here?

Tags: vocabulary

> "But, oh, Marilla, I really felt that I had tasted the bitterness of
> death, as Mr. Allan said in his sermon last Sunday, when I saw Diana
> go out alone," she said mournfully that night. "I thought how splendid
> it would have been if Diana had only been going to study for the
> Entrance, too. But we can't have things perfect in this imperfect
> world, as Mrs. Lynde says. Mrs. Lynde isn't exactly a comforting
> person sometimes, but there's no doubt she says a great many very true
> things. And I think the Queen's class is going to be extremely
> interesting. Jane and Ruby are just going to study to be teachers.
> That is the height of their ambition. Ruby says she will only teach
> for two years after she gets through, and then she intends to be
> married. Jane says she will devote her whole life to teaching, and
> never, never marry, because you are paid a salary for teaching, but a
> husband won't pay you anything, and growls if you ask for a share in
> the egg and butter money. I expect Jane speaks from mournful
> experience, for Mrs. Lynde says that her father is a perfect old
> crank, and meaner than second skimmings. Josie Pye says she is just
> going to college for education's sake, because she won't have to earn
> her own living; she says of course it is different with orphans who
> are living on charity—THEY have to hustle. Moody Spurgeon is going to
> be a minister. Mrs. Lynde says he couldn't be anything else with a
> name like that to live up to. I hope it isn't wicked of me, Marilla,
> but really the thought of Moody Spurgeon being a minister makes me
> laugh. He's such a funny-looking boy with that big fat face, and his
> little blue eyes, and his ears sticking out like flaps. But perhaps he
> will be more intellectual looking when he grows up. Charlie Sloane
> says he's going to go into politics and be a member of Parliament, but
> Mrs. Lynde says he'll never succeed at that, because the Sloanes are
> all honest people, and it's only rascals that get on in politics
> nowadays."
>
> "What is Gilbert Blythe going to be?" queried Marilla, seeing that
> Anne was **opening her Caesar**.
>
> "I don't happen to know what Gilbert Blythe's ambition in life is—if
> he has any," said Anne scornfully.
>
> –– L. M. Montgomery, Anne of Green Gables

Comment: So vote it up, Susan? Most likely the voter was offended by the reams of text and not a clearly written question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume it means that she was opening her copy of ‘De Bello Gallico’, Julius Caesar's comentary on his campaign in Gaul.

Comment: Beat me to it...

Comment: +1 It might be pointed out that this work is a very common text for second-year Latin students (or was in the days when Latin was a standard subject in high schools).

Comment: It is (was), because the Latin is perceived to be easy.